# c# assign string value based on bool value which can be nullable

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
    stringValue = microData.BoolValue.HasValue ? "True" : "False";
```

What I am trying to do is assign a stringvalue based on a Boolvalue.
if BoolValue has a value I like to do the following:

Assign stringValue = "True" if BoolValue is true.
Assign stringValue = "False" ib BoolValue is false.

If Boolvalue does not have a value, assign it to null.

What i have above does not seem to work.

Comment: You assign `stringValue` to `"False"` if `microData.BoolValue` has no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
stringValue = BoolValue.HasValue ? BoolValue.Value ? "True" : "False" : null;
```

Comment: Nested conditional operators are the devil.  Never, ever, use them.

Comment: Why? If you understand it you can use them. It's appropriate solution so why downvote?

Comment: It creates needlessly complex code that's much harder to read and understand than it needs to be, which leads to problems and bugs down the road.

Comment: I think that this construction is enough readable. If you create more nested with 3 or more so it would be hard to read but in this case I don't agree with you.

Answer (score 8):

```
stringValue = microData.BoolValue.HasValue ?
              microData.BoolValue.ToString() :
              (string)null;
```

Comment: Yeah. If the requirement was to return an empty string if `BoolValue` had no value, a simple `microData.BoolValue.ToString()` would work.